# List file sizes of all images on a page (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a Chrome Extension where you enter a page URL and it lists all the image filenames that appear on that page with the file sizes of those images e.g. "Page contains images: 1.jpg (65KB), 2.png (135KB)". How can this be done? I want to avoid making this a devtools extension as well.

I've tried using the webRequest API but I can see no way to access the body of the requests. The image size might be sent in the response header but this isn't guaranteed. I've tried using AJAX to grab the image data but the image data you get is the uncompressed version and this wouldn't be an accurate reflection of the actual file size.

Comment: Do you expect all of the images to be served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: @guest271314 You can bypass this restriction in Chrome Extensions so this shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: Did you finish this extension? I'm looking for something that does exactly this but can't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `document.images` to get images in `document`, use `fetch()`, `Response.blob()` to return `Blob` response of image, check `.size` of `Blob`, get name of image with `URL()` constructor

```js
let getImages = () => {
  let images = Array.from(document.images);
  return Promise.all(images.map(img => fetch(img.src)
    .then(response => response.blob())))
    .then(blobs => {
      return blobs.map((img, index) => {
        let name = new URL(images[index].src).pathname.split("/").pop();
        name = !/\./.test(name) 
               ? name + "." + img.type.replace(/.+\/|;.+/g, "") 
               : name;
        return {
          name: name,
          size: img.size
        }
      });
    })
}

getImages()
.then(images => console.log(JSON.stringify(images)))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/10x10">
<img src="https://placehold.it/20x20">
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the effort to write the code as well!

Comment: why do you do `let images = Array.from(document.images);` .Is `document.images` not a valid array by itself? honest question.

Comment: @Geert-Jan  [`document.images`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-images) returns an `HTMLCollection`.