# Remove background url but only AFTER an image has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, promise

I am loading an image from the client side using createObjectURL. Sometimes, the image is big, so I wanted to put a "loading" animated gif in there.

I have a container div (fileDisplay) and an img (imgDisplay).

fileDisplay has the background set to the animated gif. So, as imgDisplay is loading a big file, you see the loading gif. When imgDisplay is done loading, it covers the gif. So, its still there, but you dont see. I figured that should be fine. All is well--as long as the img is a square, which distorts the img proportions.

But, if the image loaded into imgDisplay is resized with correct proportions and not square (fileDisplay dimensions are 45x45 pixles) you still see the gif in the background.

So what I need is to be able to turn off the animated gif (background url=none on fileDisplay), or cover it with another div, or something. But only when the image has fully loaded.

I can see by now, after trying everything I can think of, that there is no way to change backgrounds, turn divs on/off, etc and do this. It seems everything is processed and then the final results are all painted at once as opposed to incrementally as if it were, say, a VB app.

Can anyone help me with working out how to do this--I'm assuming it CAN be done. And I think the solution is "promise." I have looked for samples, read what I can find, but just can't seem to grasp it.

The "uploadButton on change" event fires this code:

```
imgSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
//document.getElementById("imgDisplay" + justNumber).src = imgSrc;
getImgSize(imgSrc, useImgSize);
```

Where the commented line just displays the image as a 45x45. But the getImgSize function calculates the size and displays the image resized--which is when the problem occurs. Just try to load an image that is not square and you will see the issue.

A complete fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/msith718/xfuv79b3/334/

Answer (score 0):

So to do this you want to remove the gif/img element from the parent div when you load the new image into the div. Which you would do with the element.removeChild() function.

```js
//Put this code as soon as you want to remove the loading gif

//This gets the node or the element you want to remove
var node = document.getElementById("gif");
//This removes the node from the parent div
document.getElementById("parentDiv").removeChild(node);
```

Comment: Currently, the gif is not an img, it is the background to a div. And its parent is the same as the img I am loading the image into. I can change that if needed. But it seems the above will fire immediately. The behavior it currently has is that the background is shown while a large image takes a while to load. if the background is removed too soon, the user waits for the image to load, but with no feedback.

Comment: @msith718 Then instead of "gif" put the id of your div that;s background is the image.

Comment: that doesnt seem to do anything. the second line, where I put the parent, causes the type=upload not to work. I had the image inside the div with the background and took it out, but still no good. https://jsfiddle.net/msith718/xfuv79b3/338/

Comment: update, I put the code in the wrong spot. Nothing breaks, but it performs as I expected based on all my other efforts... it doesnt update immediately. So, if a big image is loaded, the background has been removed and, as a user, there is no feedback (animated gif) while the image loads. I need the update to happen only after the image has fully loaded. It is just a blank img. : https://jsfiddle.net/msith718/xfuv79b3/339/

Comment: well, the problem is that, if the image to load is large, it takes some time. Lets say it takes 5 seconds to load. If I put the code in to remove the child node, it happens right away... but the image has not loaded yet. So, the user is waiting for the image to load, but there is no feedback.

Comment: @msith718 Then put it after the getImgSize because that's when the image is loaded

Comment: not really. the update (removing the child node) happens right away. I need it to wait until the image has fully loaded. Otherwise, if the image to load is big, and it takes a few seconds, then there is no gif as feedback to the user. They are just looking at a blank box whlie the image loads.

Comment: it doesnt make a difference. It seems the code just continues to execute, but does not wait for any results. so, even if it is after getImgSize, and getImgSize takes a few seconds, the code after it still executes immediately (sorry for the duplicate response above, I thought the first answer didnt submit)

Comment: ive gone through every site I can. I just dont get it. Anyone?

Comment: cant even find a nice, simple, basic, example to start with.

Comment: @msith718 You need to put my code where ever when you upload the file then it shows the image right, right before that so it removes the gif/div then it shows the preview.

Comment: No. The problem is that it does not wait for the image to finish loading. When I put the code in and run it, the background disappears right away. I need it to remain until the image is finished loading. Unless I am doing something wrong... but I have put the code in after the image load and it does not work. Its driving me crazy. I am trying to create a new, simple fiddle, just for this. But just dont get it. The examples i find dont even name the img conrol.... how does it get loaded without a name or id?

Comment: At this point, I can only conclude that the internet is conspiring against me. I mean, how can there not be ONE simple example of loading an image, waiting for it to complete, and then doing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of solving this problem https://jsfiddle.net/xfuv79b3/353/. Because you are wanting to change something after the image has loaded we need to add the code somewhere after the onload event has been called. I chose to pass in an id to my imgLoader that gets passed on to the callback that processes the image once loaded. Then finally use that id to modify the background of the div once the img element has loaded the new image. What you ne

```
getImgSize(imgSrc, useImgSize, justNumber);
//...
img.onload = function() {
  fn({
    width: img.width,
    height: img.height
  },id);
}
//...
document.getElementById("imgDisplay" + id).onload=function(){
  document.getElementById('fileDisplay'+ id).style.background='none';
}
//Also to reset the background if upload is canceled
document.getElementById("fileDisplay" + justNumber).style.background = '';
```

#### Extra Note

From your reference to vb and painted I'm guessing your background is more geared towards a main loop that handles all of the interactions and holds all the data or state of your application. Javascript is very different from this in that user interactions happen through events which are asynchronous. This means data has to be explicitly passed around if need inside a certain callback.

Think about it like this. Your program starts in a resting state, but is listening for events that signal some change has happened. If an event happens (such as a user clicks a button) your program calls an event handler. This happens asynchronously meaning two things. One the only data available to it is the data passed into the handler and the data available from its parent scope. And two it means any subsequent actions or data processing have to be called from that event handler. So each event handler must perform all the actions needed and any state change updates to the program before returning to the resting state. Then your program waits for the next event.

This is very simplified (e.g. multiple events can be fired at the same time) and hopefully helpful, but once you get the hang of it javascript makes a whole lot more sense. I'd suggest reading up on event driven programming with javascript since I'm sure there are much better tutorials and explanations out there, but hopefully this gets you headed in the right direction.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation but the new fiddle doenst do it. It also removes the background immediately. so, if a large img is loaded, and it takes, lets say, 5 seconds to load, there is just a blank space for 5 seconds. Maybe I am not explaining this well, but I looks like I need to find another way to give user feedback or another way to load an image. I was hoping this was a simple thing to do for someone more experienced but maybe it is more difficult than I was expecting--any sample I find is certainly not simple and straightforward.

Comment: @msith718 I updated my answer and jsfiddle example. I needed to add one more onload handler to the img tag itself. I also added the code to remove the background adjustment if the image upload was canceled.

Comment: Thank you so much. Not only does this help me get past the immediate problem but, more importantly, it is exactly what I was hoping to find--a simple, straightforward example that can be used to understand what is going on here (I think). In this example, I can make sense of what is going on. Sort of. It's still very confusing to me.

Comment: I can see, now, that fn is the name of the funcion that is called from getImgSize and that it does the work of loading. But in getImgSize is where you turn off the fileDisplay background. But why does that work? If the image has been loaded at this point, surely it is loaded after the getImgSize call, but turning the background off at that point did not work?

Comment: I have a ton more questions but I will spend tonight going over this, modify and playing, until it makes sense. I cant thank you enough.

Comment: Although, suddenly, it does not work again. ARGGGG! The background image disappears too soon. It was working fine, at first. Did i do something?

Comment: Im testing with images that are 5, 8, and 12 megs.  At first, I thought maybe they were cached after the first load. But they still take a few seconds, so I dont think that is the issue.

Comment: @msith718 one thing I forgot to mention that you can do to sidestep the whole issue is use css to set the background of the img tag to the loading animation. When the image loads it will cover up the background, but only once it loads.

Comment: i was just playing with that idea. It works great EXCEPT that the img is resized so the background is also resized... and so looks all distorted. The image can be any dimension (likely not square) but the loading background is square.

Comment: actually, the loading image isnt distorted, it is just cropped as the img dimensions change

Comment: Ok. It seems something funny is going on with cacheing the image. When I run something as simple as : <img src="myBigImg" onload="alert('test');" /> it works fine. The alert does not come until the image is fully loaded. But, subsequent runs show the alert immediately--but the image still takes a few more seconds to load. This must be why when I first ran your code, it worked fine. But then stopped working. Although I tried other images--I think--one of those situations where you try so much stuff you lose track.

Comment: In case any one checks for this, I figured I'd add my solution. It isnt a solution to the issue but an alternate approach that is actually a better approach. Instead of keep the image proportions, I decided to do what my phone does when displaying images in a gallery. Reduce and crop. This keep everything square and undistorted, just cropping equal amounts from top/bottom or left/right depending on the dimensions. This allows the use of the img background which works flawlessly-no need to try and hide or change divs. works like a charm.